# close uitableview and reload another uitableview

Tags: tableview, reload, segue

i have problem.

I have CityViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
  TheatreController *tmpTheatreController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheatreController"];
  NSString *cityView = [[self.arrayCity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"idCity"];
  tmpTheatreController.cityView = cityView;

  //[self.navigationController pushViewController:tmpTheatreController animated:YES];
  [tmpTheatreController.tableView reloadData];
  [self.delegate citiesViewControllerCancel:self];    
}
```

When i select the city pass correctly the "idCity" in TheatreController.m

```
...
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SelectCity"])
   {
      UINavigationController *nc = segue.destinationViewController;
      CityViewController *mvc = [[nc viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
      mvc.delegate = self;
   }
}
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];


  NSString *webUrl = @"http://localhost:3000/theatres?city=";
  webUrl = [webUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", cityView];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webUrl]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES]; });
    }
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
   NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                 JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                 options:kNilOptions error:nil];
   NSMutableArray *theatreTMP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[json count]];

   int i = 0;
   for (id object in [json valueForKeyPath:@"response.name"]) {
     Theatres *t = [[Theatres alloc] init];
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [[json valueForKeyPath:@"response.name"] objectAtIndex:i]);
     t.theatre = [[json valueForKeyPath:@"response.name"] objectAtIndex:i];
     t.idTheatre = [[json valueForKeyPath:@"response.id"] objectAtIndex:i];

     [theatreTMP addObject:t];
     i++;
  }
 self.arrayTheatre = [theatreTMP copy];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I have correctly the response of the server and all parameter are correct, but the problem i have with reloadData of the tableView main![enter image description here][1]. I dont see the update table.

HELP ME thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved with this solution
In the CityViewController.m

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cityView = [[self.arrayCity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"idCity"];
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(reloadTable:) withObject:cityView];
    [self.delegate citiesViewControllerCancel:self];
}
```

and in the TheatreTableView.m

```
    - (void) callServer:(NSString *)idCity {
    NSString *webUrl = @"http://localhost:3000/theatres?city=";
    webUrl = [webUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", idCity];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webUrl]];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];});
}
....
- (void) reloadTable:(id)idCity
{
    [self callServer:idCity];
}
```

Thanks